# Typescript: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a .ts file in node js (latest version of node.js for 07.10.19) app with importing node-module without default export. I use this construction: `import { Class } from 'abc';` When i run the code, i have this error: `Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

In the network i see many solutions for this problem (for .js), but it not helps to me, maybe because i have typescript file. Here's my code:

```
import { Class } from 'abc';
module.exports = { ...
    execute(a : Class ,args : Array<string>){ ...
```

Here's my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",

    "strict": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you running this in a browser? Is the `import` statement the first line in your file?

Comment: Can you please post your tsconfig.json file? When you compile in Typescript, you can determine which type of modules it produces, and the valid types may differ depending on which environment (browser/NodeJS) and which other modules (`require` vs `import`) you use. Just to give you a sense of how complicated this is, Node has some [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling) about `import` vs `require` and how to make them work together.

Comment: If you are using `module.exports` syntax, you're probably not in an ES6 module.

Comment: Ok, i can't use require because Cannot find namespace 'abc' when using construction `execute(a : abc.Class...`

Answer (score 129, accepted):

*Update: Because this answer is getting significant views I have updated it to better show the available solutions for this problem in 2022.*

---

The error means Node found an `import` statement in a file that it does not consider an ECMAScript (ES) module. [Adding `"type": "module"` to `package.json`](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#type) will tell Node you are using ES modules, but then you will need to tell the TypeScript compiler to emit this type of module by setting `"module": "es2015"` or higher (for example: `"es2020"`) in `tsconfig.json` . If you want to emit CommonJS modules (`require`), set `"module": "commonjs"`.

In case you don't want to set the module system at the project level, there are more fine-grained options. Files with the `.mjs` extension are always treated as ES modules, while files with `.cjs` are always treated as CommonJS modules. As of TypeScript 4.5 it is possible to use the `.mts` and `.cts` extensions as well and have the compiler emit `.mjs` or `.cjs` files, respectively.

The two systems are partially compatible. For example, it is possible to import a CommonJS module into an ES module with a default export:

```
// in an ES module
import thing from "./main.cjs";
```

The other way around. an ES module may be imported into a CommonJS module with dynamic import (ES2020 features are needed for this to work):

```
// in a CommonJS module
const thing = await import("./main.mjs");
```

---

###### Original answer (2020):

Adding `"type": "module"` to `package.json` will tell Node you are using ES2015 modules, which should get rid of the error, but then you will need to tell Typescript to generate this type of module by setting `"module": "es2015"` instead of `"commonjs"` in `tsconfig.json`.

This however causes a problem with the current code because although you are using an ES6 `import {}` statement you are exporting using the commonJS `module.exports = {}` syntax, and Node’s ES module loader will have an issue with it. There are two ways to deal with it:

- Keep the module.exports but tell Node to interpret this file as commonJS by giving it a .cjs extension.
- Change the export statement to ES2015 syntax: `export function execute(…)..`

The first option could get a bit tricky because the compiler will output .js files and you’d have to change it to .cjs all the time (as far as I know). With the second option you should be able to run the file with Node (including the --experimental-modules flag for versions < 13.8).

If you absolutely need to use commonJS, perhaps it is better to install the type definitions for Node: `@types/node` and change the import to commonJS format: `require('abc')` and keep the rest of the settings as they are (though you can add `"type": "commonjs"` to package.json to be explicit).

Comment: I get the error that: "ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead" for the bundle that webpack generates? How do I prevent this?

Comment: note for myself: if you never write `module.exports` then you just need to read the first paragraph.

Comment: I made vice-versa! I changed in tsconfig.json to "module" : "CommonJS" and removed "type":"module" in package.json and it helped me :D

Comment: Why did I even remove `"type": "module"` :D

Answer (score 137):

If you happen to be using `ts-node`, you can set some compiler options in `tsconfig.json` specifically for `ts-node` to use.

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    // these options are overrides used only by ts-node
    // same as the --compilerOptions flag and the TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS environment variable
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs"
    }
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext"
  }
}
```

Then you can just execute your script pretty easily:

```sh
$ ts-node my-script.ts
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I've got this issue with hardhat when integrating it in a nextjs app where both came with different tsconfigs.

Comment: This is should be accept answer! I can run it without type as "module" and change ts to mts

Comment: This is the way, especially in projects like create-react-app that come with a built in tsconfig!

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. I ended up having to also add `"esModuleInterop": true` to make the lodash import work (otherwise `_` ended up being `undefined`)

Comment: This works perfectly for me. I happen to run this ts-node as a postdeploy command in my SST NextJS project. Weirdly enough, it works fine in my SST Lambda Project

Answer (score 18):

Make sure your `"main"` field in `package.json` is pointing to the compiled `index.js` and not the `index.ts`

Answer (score 7):

## Solution if `"type": "module"` is NOT an option

- rename `.ts` to `.mts`
- run `ts-node --esm file.mts`

here's my `tsconfig.json` for reference:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["**/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had very similar issue. I had to install **nodemon** and always start script through `nodemon index.ts`

```
yarn add -D nodemon
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "nodemon index.ts"
}
```

or to specify the file from the command line

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
   "nodemon": "nodemon $1"
}
```

Comment: This seems to work for me (with `ts-node` installed, using `import` statements without `"type": "module" in package.json.

Answer (score 1):

There can be a lot of of possibilities for getting,

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

while running typescript.

In my setup, I was importing a module called, `AbModule` (`AbModule` has class `AbClassName`) from my script `testab.ts`.

`testab.ts` had `import stmt`,

```
import {AbClassName} = 'testAdapterDir/AbModule.po.ts';
```

However,
`AbModule` had all `*.ts` files and there were `*.js` files were not present.
fix is,

> You may get errors in running the below code but you can safely ignore them.

```sh
cd AbModule path
tsc *.ts
```

Now `AbModule` should contain compiled files all `*.js` too.
Now run `testab.ts` and noticed that the mentioned error does not exist anymore,

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with one Node TypeScript project. I needed some features of ESM, and when changed `"target"` and `"module"` in `tsconfig.json` to `ESNext`, I've got an error "Cannot use import statement outside a module".

The solution helped me was:

1. implement `"type": "module"` in `package.json`
2. implement `"target": "ESNext"` and `"module": "NodeNext"` in `tsconfig.json` (afterwards I checked  that `"module": "ESNext"` worked as well by the way)
3. change all import statement in `*.ts` files adding `js` extension like this `import { AccountGroup } from "./AccountGroup.js"` (despite that actual code in TypeScript project before compilation is inside `AccountGroup.ts` file)

Solution was found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html) and was inspired by this [source](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c#how-can-i-make-my-typescript-project-output-esm)

Answer (score 0):

## For Monorepo

> Issue: A workspace A outputs "Typescript: Cannot use import statement outside a module" because of a dependent typescript workspace B.

### Steps:

##### workspace B

1. Define a `composite: true` in the `compileOptions` (tsconfig) in workspace B

```html
{
  ...,                 
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "composite": true
  }
}
```

2. Set the `main` field to the index.js of in the `outDir` for the package.

##### workspace A

1. Define the `references` key in the root of the tsconfig to take an array of object with `path` key and a value that references the relative path to workspace B tsconfig.

```html
{
 ...,
  "references": [
    {"path": "../../workspace B"}
  ]
}
```

2. Build your project with `tsc -b` and run your project with `node` pointing to the built index.js in workspace A. e.g. `node build/index.js`

You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In `tsconfig.json` change the module to `"module": "es2016"` or later then this issue: Can not import statement outside module: Will not appear on running the node app.js files.

[image: target]

Answer (score -1):

### Node v20 & type: module & module: ESNext

It seems like Node introduced a breaking change in v20. See [here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1997#issuecomment-1517388341).

You can use `node --loader ts-node/esm src/index.ts` but people complain of high resource usage. See [here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1997#issuecomment-1537187921).

I ended up using `npx tsc; node build/index.js` as suggested [here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1997#issuecomment-1535225677).