# How to get VS Code to show / validate object schema?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

[image]

1. npm init -y
2. npm i axios
3. npm i @types/axios --save-dev

How come VS code 1.62 doesn't appear to give the schema of the response object when I am typing out code like:

```
resp = await axios("https://httpstat.us/404");
resp.
```

`<C-Space>` shows confusing / inappropriate completions.

What am I missing please? I tried renaming the file to typescript and that doesn't help either, so I am really confused how to edit Javascript effectively. I.e. for the editor to diagnose that I am using the wrong properties and prompt for using the right ones with documentation.

Comment: Does this help ? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_troubleshooting/  or try create local variable instead of using global variables. `const resp = ...`

Comment: no, it doesn't really help. require() = no sane completion

Comment: Visit that URL in a browser...

Answer (score 0):

Name the file with a `.ts` extension and import `axios` with:

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

Then the following should work with full autocompletion:

```
async function testing() {
  const resp = await axios("https://httpstat.us/404");
  resp.status // works
}
```

Typescript doesn't always get the types right with the `require` function. `import` is the right way you do this in typescript.

[See the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

Comment: But with imports, you can't run it? `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: Try adding `export` to something in that file. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58273824/typescript-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module