# the Example code of TS can't run but return an Error

Tags: typescript

In the website https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/,I want learn more about the TS,so I want to run the Example code of TS,then I want I can get a result of these Example code,however ,I just get an error .

this is the link of one of the example code of Playground for TS:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCpAD0ljkwFcA7DYCZuRgZyQBkIKACbBmAcwAUASjgBvCnDhoO3eAG1g3AcNFiANHF4wAyjBQwkAXTgBeRMRgA6HklPmkEzCgA2vKQG4FJRV4b0EhWzgJFAAFHBBNJAAuODjcRIAeFGYATwA+GRs8uSDFIzcLCRgoRiQA0rgiGEYoTlj4xMdMUR9vHIlpW2Lys0qvXzr68kUAX0DpxqRm1rgNLXDdAzDhaxRuYOZVfzgAehO4UUwkKH21ACMICG9UZgMYHLAkCEw4baFrUSqVARb5RB5PF5wAA+cHen1BfykaksFBmQA

after I click run,then I get an Error as follow:

```
[ERR] "Executed JavaScript Failed:"

[ERR]: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

JavaScript language version is ES2020

Comment: The error is pretty clear though... you cannot use an `import` statement in the typescript playground. It's better to use codepen or codesandbox for testing react code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58273824/typescript-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)

Comment: "Typescript: Cannot use import statement outside a module",this is not solve my question.but I can use codepen or codesandbox to test react code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're reading the instructions carefully enough: the [tutorial setup page](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/setup) says 'TypeScript Playground with React: just if you are debugging types (and reporting issues), **not for running code**' (my emphasis).

The [CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ts?utm_source=dotnew) on the next line seems to run the code fine with React in the cloud.