# inability to use `ts-node` or `node` to serve `index.ts` file but `nodemon` works... why?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack, nodemon

Have been wrestling with this for a couple days now... Writing a TypeScript, React, Express, Node, Webpack and Babel project. First, I was getting the `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`
error trying to use `import` syntax in my `src/server/index.ts` file and serving it with `node src/server/index.ts` in my `start` script.

but this works: `nodemon src/server/index.ts` as a `start` script.

Can anyone explain to me *why* `nodemon` works but `node` and `ts-node` do not?

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "ts-node": { /* EDIT: these ts-node options apparently are very important... */
    "compilerOptions": { /* if i remove these lines, even _with_ nodemon, I get the first error: */
      "module": "commonjs" /* `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` */
    }
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "nodenext",
    "lib": [
      "DOM",
      "ESNext"
    ],
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noEmit": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/client/**/*"
  ]
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

const paths = {
  DIST: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  SRC_ENTRY: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'client', 'Index.tsx'),
  HTML_TEMPLATE: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'client', 'index.html'),
};

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: paths.SRC_ENTRY,
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: paths.DIST,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use:
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: paths.HTML_TEMPLATE }),
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

`src/server/index.ts`

```
import express, { Express } from 'express'; /* <-- this is the first import where the error is thrown */
import path from 'path';

export const app: Express = express();
/* ... */
```

Tried many different fixes including the outdated and popular "add `"type": "module"` to your `package.json` file, as well as changing around my "target", "moduleResolution", "module", "allowJS" and basically any other relevant property in my `tsconfig.json`...

**I have provided my code above, but for the tl;dr,** `npm i --save-dev nodemon` if you don't already have it globally installed and change your "start" script in your `package.json` to `nodemon your/path/to/file.ts` and you can use `import` syntax in your server file to serve.

**To reiterate..** this problem was fixed by adding the `ts-node` options to my `tsconfig.json` and installing and implementing `nodemon` instead of node. I just don't understand why that fixes it and was hoping someone would help me out with that...

here is the outdated but classic SO solution with "type": "module" in `package.json`: [ol' faithful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)
as well as an "updated" solution from 2022 that also did *not* work for me: [most recent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60225870/20575174)

Comment: Its good to be curious and learn stuff. However, I think you are using some outdated material to learn.  Webpack and especially express are not really used for greenfield projects. Perhaps look at the [vite react starter](https://vitejs.dev/guide/), that lets you focus on coding instead of wrestling with wepack and ts. In some cases (SPA), you also dont want to serve the react  app from the backend. You can serve statics by simplier and more efficient means, i.e. nginx or blob storage.