Server.ts not able to run because of issue with ES vs CommonJS in Angular project
I have an Angular project where I am using PostgreSQL and Express for my backend. Angular automatically provides a server.ts file. However, I do not understand how to start the server because I get this error:
Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension. (Use 'node --trace-warnings ...' to show where the warning was created) *path/to/file*/server.ts:1 import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
I have tried to set "type": "module" and tried using the .mjs extension. However, these both result in errors since I import other files which are .ts; and, I don't believe they're the best solutions since Angular provides a .ts file to begin with.
My public repo: https://github.com/ColeWhaley1/Educational-Web-App/tree/basic-api
Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

You can't run .ts with node because it's not valid js. Renaming a file doesn't make sense. Use ts-node or tsx if you don't want to deal with explicit ts compilation

I have tried that, but it gives an error "Cannot use import statement outside a module". I tried to change it to use require instead, but then it gives another error "require() of ES Module .../common.mjs not supported".

Which of them did you try? require() isn't normally used with TS. You need to specifically address issues, not switch between random solutions. E.g. if you have problem with ts-node, it's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58273824/typescript-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module .
